# Bigcommerce - Is it possible to change text after a function executes?

Tags: javascript, html, bigcommerce

I'm working on a site right now, and there is some text that I want to change. The site has a search feature in the header, and after you type 3 or 4 characters in the input field, a product list drops down listing products that have those characters in the product name (similar to: http://www.lightexports.com/). I want to change the text that appears at the bottom of that list, "View all results".

I tried using the .replace() function but that doesn't work, and i can't use a window.onload because if you never use the search, then the code never gets loaded on the site. The code to display the list of products and the text that i want to change only appears after you start typing in the search bar.

**NOTE: The platform I'm using is Bigcommerce and only allows HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance and happy coding!

Comment: for elements created dynamically in js, you have to delegate events.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.  The best way7 to accomplish this:

1. Download the quicksearch.js file that loads on your site -- it is queued in `Snippets/QuickSearchJS.html` and you can download it by navigating to `yourstore.com/javascript/quicksearch.js`.
2. Upload this file to your WebDav folder `/template/js/`
3. In your `Snippets/QuickSearchJS.html` Snippet file, which you can edit from the BigCommerce backend "Design > Edit HTML/CSS" page, comment out the original `<script>` tag and add a tag to point to the JS file you uploaded to your WebDav.  The new `Snippets/QuickSearchJS.html` file should look like this:

   ```
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_CdnAppPath%%/javascript/quicksearch.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="%%ASSET_js/quicksearch.js%%?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
   ```

(Yes, I know the syntax looks weird but only because of the way ASSET is used and the way cachetoken must also have %%.  This syntax is correct.)

4. In the quicksearch.js that you uploaded via WebDav to your js folder, edit the following lines, around lines 184-195:

   ```
       if(all_results_count)
       {
           var tr = document.createElement('TR');
           var td = document.createElement('TD');
           tr.className = "QuickSearchAllResults";
           tr.onmouseover = function() { QuickSearch.over_all = true; };
           tr.onmouseout = function() { QuickSearch.over_all = false; };
           td.colSpan = 2;
           td.innerHTML = $('viewmoreurl', response).text();
           tr.appendChild(td);
           popup.appendChild(tr);
       }
   ```

so that they look like this:

```
        if(all_results_count)
        {
            var tr = document.createElement('TR');
            var td = document.createElement('TD');
            tr.className = "QuickSearchAllResults";
            tr.onmouseover = function() { QuickSearch.over_all = true; };
            tr.onmouseout = function() { QuickSearch.over_all = false; };
            td.colSpan = 2;
            td.innerHTML = 'YOUR NEW CUSTOM TEXT/NAME FOR THE "View All Results" LINK GOES HERE';
            tr.appendChild(td);
            popup.appendChild(tr);
        }
```

Put your new name of the "View All Results" link in between the ' and ' at the line that starts with `td.innerHTML =`

5. Now just save and refresh your page, and your text will be changed natively, without having to write JS and to watch for events or to delegate any actions.

---

Please let me know if this helped or if you have any questions.